# Rendering SSRS Reports through SOAP Webservice by Java application

Tags: java, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, soap-client

I am trying to render SSRS reports using Java application using SSRS SOAP API.

I was following the instructions given in the following article.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/christophputz/2010/05/07/accessing-ms-reporting-services-with-java/

Following this article, I was able to generate stub classes (Proxy classes) for rendering reports.

I have generated stubs using following two end-points.

```
wsimport http://192.168.8.66:8081/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx?wsdl  –s src2

wsimport http://192.168.8.66:8081/ReportServer/reportService2005.asmx?wsdl –s src
```

However, when I was implementing the Java app, I found that the following classes are missing amoung the generated stubs.

```
ReportExecutionService res = new ReportExecutionService();
ReportExecutionServiceSoap ress = res.getReportExecutionServiceSoap();

ExecutionInfo execInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
```

Could anybody having experience using SOPA API advice me what is the reason for this and, if these classes are deprecated, what are the updated classes that I should be using. Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint you need to use to get wsdl for report execution is http://192.168.8.66:8081/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx?wsdl.